# Chrome on Ubuntu - How to open split screen (50% / 50%) tabs on startup via command line

Tags: google-chrome

How to open Chrome split screen (50% / 50%) tabs on startup via command line (Ubuntu, bash script)?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if Chrome supports such window-splitting at all, but you can always write a simple (local) HTML page that contains two frames, with URL 1 in the left frame and URL 2 in the right frame, and open that page in Chrome.

Comment: @raj - yes, that would be a good workaround